# Preload data into Angular 2 Form

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm newbie in Angular 2 development. I'm developing an Angular application with Visual Studio Angular SPA template and with .Net Core 2.0.

I have this component html file:

```
<h1>L&iacute;neas</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!lines"><em>Loading...</em></p>
<form #lineForm="ngForm">
    <table class='table' *ngIf="lines">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Line Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Line Reference Id</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let line of lines">
                <td>{{ line.lineId }}</td>
                <td><input [(ngModel)]="line.name" placeholder="name" required></td>
                <td><input [(ngModel)]="line.lineReferenceId" placeholder="lineReferenceId" required></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And its TypeScript file:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'line',
    templateUrl: './line.component.html'
})
export class LineComponent {
    public lines: Line[];

    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Line').subscribe(result => {
            this.lines = result.json() as Line[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface Line {
    lineId: number;
    name: string;
    lineReferenceId: string;
}
```

I want to load some data into the form to allow user to edit it, but it shows to rows (I retrieve to lines) but without data.

If I remove the form tags, it shows the two rows with the data.

Without form:

---

[image]

With form:

---

[image]

**Do I need to do something else to show the data?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the fields don't have a name or an Id, this is why they don't show the data.

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let line of lines">
        <td>{{ line.lineId }}</td>
        <td><input [(ngModel)]="line.name" placeholder="name" required name="name-{{line.lineId}}"></td>
        <td><input [(ngModel)]="line.lineReferenceId" placeholder="lineReferenceId" name="lineReferenceId-{{line.lineId}}" required></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```